# C# Linq Find all indexes of item in List<int> within another List<int>

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a List looks like:

```
List<int> List1= new List<int>(){3,4,5};
```

and another looks like:

```
List<int> List2 = new List<int>(){1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

How can I use Linq to get an array of all of the indices of List1 from List2 like below:

```
var ResultList = {2,3,4};
```

Comment: I don't get it, why is the result is 2, 3, and 4?

Comment: @WillyDavidJr those are the 0 based indexes in `List2` of the search items in `List1`

Comment: I get it, thanks @StuartLC

Comment: @Karaiden can there be more than one instance of the values in `List1` inside `List2`, and if so, do you want to list all such instances?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var ResultList = List1.Select(x => List2.IndexOf(x));
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a longer solution but prevents a nested loop through the array which may be faster if the arrays are huge (but slower if the arrays are small).

```
List<int> List1= new List<int>(){3,4,5};
List<int> List2 = new List<int>(){1,2,3,4,5,6};

var lookup = new Dictionary<int, int>();
for(var i=0; i<List2.Count; i++) {
    lookup[List2[i]] = i;
}

List<int> Result = List1.Select(i => {
    int index;
    return lookup.TryGetValue(i, out index) ? index : -1;
}).ToList();
```

Comment: @caesay totally depends on use case. In actual production code a lot of it would get abstracted away to other enumerable extension methods and would be just as succinct as your answer.

Comment: I just profiled this (i was curious) and this answer becomes more effective if you're dealing with lists of items in the 6 digits (around 200k).

Answer (score 1):

You can also do the overloaded version of Select statement to select the Value and return the Index:

```
var result = List2.Select((a, b) => new {Value = a, Index = b})
                          .Where(x => List1.Any(d => d == x.Value))
                          .Select(c => c.Index).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `List2` contains more than one instance of a List1 value (or Equality) type, then you can use the [indexed overload of `Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to find all the duplicates:

```
var List1= new List<int>(){3,4,5};
var List2 = new List<int>(){1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,5};   

var result = List2.Select((x, idx) => Tuple.Create(x, idx))
    .Where(t => List1.Contains(t.Item1))
    .Select(x => x.Item2)

// 2,3,4,8,9
```

or better, using C#7 Value Tuples

```
List2.Select((x, idx) => (X:x, Idx:idx))
        .Where(t => List1.Contains(t.X))
        .Select(x => x.Idx);
```

(`.IndexOf` returns just the first index found in the target)